# Refactor small function using lodash/fp map, and a second argument

Tags: reactjs, lodash

I have a lodash/fp `map` function that returns a component, `Lead`. It is passed a list of `leads` (over which I iterate), but I also want to pass an id, that ill pass into each component (same id into each component)

I pass the array and the string into the component:

```
<tbody>{renderLeads(leads, advisor.id)}</tbody>
```

and my function returns a mapped array of leads:

```
const renderLeads = map(({ node: lead }) => { <--- how do i pass advisor.id into this function
   return <Lead lead={lead} advisorId={advisorId} key={lead.id} />;
});
```

How do I add the prop `advisor.id` (the second argument) into that map?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use currying to generate the map's callback with the `advisorId`:

```
const renderLeads = pipe( // pipe is an alias of `_.flow()`
  advisorId => ({ node: lead }) => (
    <Lead lead={lead} advisorId={advisorId} key={lead.id} />
  ),
  map
);
```

To use it:

```
<tbody>{renderLeads(advisor.id)(leads)}</tbody>
```

Example:

```js
const { pipe, map } = _;

const Lead = ({ lead, advisorId }) => (
  <div>{lead.txt} : {advisorId}</div>
);

const renderLeads = pipe(
  advisorId => ({ node: lead }) => (
    <Lead lead={lead} advisorId={advisorId} key={lead.id} />
  ),
  map
);

const Demo = ({ leads, advisor }) => (
  <div>{renderLeads(advisor.id)(leads)}</div>
);

const leads = [{ node: { id: 1, txt: 'lead-1' }}, { node: { id: 2, txt: 'lead-2' }}, { node: { id: 3, txt: 'lead-3' }}];

ReactDOM.render(
  <Demo leads={leads} advisor={{ id: '154' }} />,
  root
);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/lodash@4(lodash.min.js+lodash.fp.min.js)'></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: is `pipe` a lodash/fp thing? i thought they used `flow`

Comment: `_.flow()` exists in lodash and lodash/fp, `_.pipe()` is an alias of `_.flow()` in lodash/fp.